# Finding closest points to a multidimensional data point?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dimension

I have a dataset that gives the values of some songs, ie something that looks like:

```
    acousticness danceability energy instrumentalness key  liveness  loudness 
0        0.223      0.780      0.72       0.111        1     0.422    0.231
1        0.4        0.644      0.88       0.555        0.5   0.66     0.555
2        0.5        0.223      0.145      0.76         0     0.144    0.567
.
.
.
```

I want to find the songs/ rows that are numerically closest together by these points. I have already reduced the dimensions by removing other highly correlated variables, so this is seemingly the lowest dimension. Does anyone know how I can do this? It likely requires a machine learning algorithm but I don't really know where to start.

Comment: look at `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scipy.spital.distance.euclidean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html#scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean) to calculate the distance between two multidimetional points.

In your case e.g.

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance
d = distance.euclidean([0.223, 0.780, 0.72, 0.111, 1, 0.422, 0.231], [0.4, 0.644, 0.88, 0.555, 0.5, 0.66, 0.555])
print(d)
```

You don't need machine learning for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Would give distance of each row form all other rows

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
song_index_and_dist = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for k in range(i+1,df.shape[0]):
        song_index_and_dist.append([i,k,distance.euclidean(df.loc[i],df.loc[k])])
print(pd.DataFrame(song_index_and_dist))
```